# Larger subset with smaller weight sum ("inverse" Weighted Interval Scheduling Prob.)

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, intervals

I want to find a variation of the WIS problem where the result must be the larger subset with minimum weight sum. For example, in:

```
    Input: Number of Intervals n = 5
            Interval Details: (start-finish, weight)
            Interval 1:  (0-5, 15) 
            Interval 2:  (4-9, 18)
            Interval 3:  (10-15, 12)
            Interval 4:  (8-21, 19)
            Interval 5:  (25-30, 25)
```

The answer must be the subset {3, 1, 5} since this is the subset with maximum elements and minimum weight sum ws = 52 ( 12 + 15 + 25).

This problem is part of a project and I googled a lot for this but found anything in this way. I'm not familiar with algorithms and programming so sorry if I'm writing something stupid here.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What input size are we dealing with? It looks like this problem is NP-complete, because in the worst case we need to compute all possible largest subsets, and select the one with the minimum weight sum.

Comment: @Jakob, somewhere around 40 intervals. A friend suggested me to find the size K of the largest subset of non-overlapping intervals and then use brute force to find all combination of K intervals and get the one with minimum weight sum. This may work for me, but I don't know how to obtain all subsets of K elements containing only non-overlapping intervals. Do you know some algorithm that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force approach: find all possible starting intervals and all possible last intervals and compute all possible sequences between starting and end intervals. This is equal to calculating all paths between pairs of nodes in a Directed Acyclic Graph(DAG).

Compute starting intervals:

- Find minimum finish time.
- Starting intervals are all intervals with starting time < minimum finish time. If you started with another job, you would need to omit one interval.

Similarly, compute end intervals:

- Find maximum starting time.
- End intervals are all intervals with finish time > maximum starting time.

Compute all paths between these two sets: 
 Here you need to apply an algorithm which computes all paths in a DAG. Implementations can be found on the internet. One example:

```
void recursive(Interval current, Interval destination, List<Interval> path)
{
    path.Add(current);

    if (current == destination)
    { 
        if (path.Count > maxLength || (path.Count == maxLength && pathWeight < minWeight))
        {
            minWeightPath = new List<Interval>(path);
        }
        path.Remove(current);
        return;
    }

    //Successors are all intervals with startTime >= current.finishTime
    List<Interval> possibleSuccessors = getAllSuccessors();

    foreach (var item in possibleSuccessors)
    {
        recursive(item, destination, path);
    }

    path.Remove(current);
}
```

Call this method the following way:

```
foreach (var startNode in startingNodes)
{
    List<Interval> path = new List<Interval>();
    foreach (var endNode in endNodes)
    {
        if (startNode.finishTime < endNode.startTime)
            recursive(startNode, endNode, path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot!